# Jupyter notebook throwing out this error - 'NameError: name 'VAR' is not defined'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

any advice on the above error being thrown out on the code below, could be much appreciated:

```
today = date.today().strftime("%d%m%Y")
for index, row in df_audio.iterrows():
    print(f'{index}_speech_{today}', row.url)
    start_transcription(bucket_name, f'{index}_speech_{today}_{var}', row.url, wait_process=False)
    df_audio.at[index, 'transcription_url'] = f"https://{bucket_name}.s3.amazonaws.com/{index}_speech_{today}.json"
    df_audio.at[index, 'json_transcription'] = f"{index}_speech_{today}.json"
```

Comment: I'm following along this tutorial (https://towardsdatascience.com/analyzing-historical-speeches-using-amazon-transcribe-and-comprehend-636f39a0726a) and it's failing because of the var in #9

Comment: It means that you haven't defined `var`? Are you expecting it to be defined?

Comment: I just removed {var}  and the code seems to have run...

Comment: If you need it, then define it and set a value, otherwise it's redundant.

Comment: unfortunately the tutorial is not available for free (if you used up the monthly quota, which is my case). You can provide better context of what `var` is, in this case you just haven't defined `var` before. `var` is only used for naming in your case within the fstring